# Computer displays stuck/damaged pixels normally, and then fails to show them when in fullscreen/popup

Tags: display, dead-pixel, stuck-pixel

my laptop (ROG Strix G17 G713IM-DS71-CA) has recently started displaying a small circle of stuck pixels in the middle right of the screen. I was researching possible ways to solve this when I noticed that dragging a popped-out video across the circle caused it to disappear until the popup was removed.

Further experimentation revealed that in normal operation, the circle is visible, as well as a darker area surrounding it, but when that part of the screen is covered by a popup, or the system is in fullscreen, such as when I am playing a game or watching a video, the area is fine. I've included some images of before and after. As a side note, the laptop seldom leaves my room, and is always in a laptop bag when it does, so I'm not sure how it could have been damaged.

Note: I noticed a similar problem when looking through this forum, and the recommended fix was changing the framerate. I tried changing the screen from 144 to 60 Hz, but the problem persisted.

Screen normally:
[image: Screen normally]

Screen covered by popup:
[image: Screen covered by popup]

Comment: If it goes away when covered by a popup it is not stuck pixels. Please [edit] and add your operating system tag.

Answer (score 0):

**If** the pixels are actually sticking, but are only stuck occasionally, try a tools such as SoftwareOK's [IsMyLcdOK](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/IsMyLcdOK), which can present screens of a solid color to make bad pixels more obvious, and which can "exercise" pixels, sometimes fixing the issue.

Though the pixel flipping procedure works only occasionally, it's worth trying the free app, which needs no installation. It's also useful when you want to clean the screen, in the midst of a session, and want it all *black* to see smudges.